# Split destination into city, region and country

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
var str = "Orlando (and vicinity), Florida, United States of America";
```

I want to split this string to hold city, region and country in Javascript.

```
Eg: city - Orlando
    region - Florida
    country - United States Of America
```

Comment: You mean _Split by comma_

Comment: split on `,` would be the way to go

Comment: `.split(/\s*,\s*/g)` to "trim" the resulting strings

Comment: Yes . by comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below, I've inserted them in a object.

```js
var str = "Orlando (and vicinity), Florida, United States of America";

data = str.split(',')
city = data[0].match(/^\w+/g)

res = {
'city': city[0],
'region': data[1],
'country': data[2]
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create an object that holds the key:values, based on the split:

```
let str = "Orlando (and vicinity), Florida, United States of America";

let locationData = {city: "", region: "", country: ""};

let result = str.split(",")

locationData.city = result[0];
locationData.region = result[1];
locationData.country = result[2];
```

However splitting the string like this is not reliable.